# Merge 2 csv files as it is

Tags: batch-file, csv, merge

I want to merge 2 csv files. For example csv1 file contains first six columns and csv2 file contains (first 6 columns empty) 7th,8th,9th columns.In the merged csv, i need as it is(first 6 columns --first csv and 7,8,9----second csv).kindly help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please put examples of csv data types: does it contain special batch symbols eg. ()!.? I don't see a way to read data from both files in parallel in batch. So one file needs to be pre-read. I'd suggest to use VB or C# for your task instead.

Comment: no special batch symbols.i tried type*.csv>merged.csv.but it is copying csv2 file in 7,8,9th columns but not csv1... i dono why?

Comment: Post a short example of both files and the result you want, PLEASE!

Comment: Also I assume that both csv files have same number of lines. And there're no empty lines in the csv.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that file1.csv have lines with this format:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6
```

and that file2.csv have lines with this format:

```
,,,,,,col7,col8,col9
```

The Batch file below create the merged file with col1..col6 from file1, and col7..col9 from file2; it assume that both files have the same number of lines and that there are not empty lines in any file.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

< file2.csv (
   for /F "delims=" %%a in (file1.csv) do (
      set /P line2=
      echo %%a,!line2:~6!
   )
) > merged.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that files are not too big to load them into memory and there're not more than 999999 lines in each csv file. CMD will exit immediately as script ends.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set file1Content=
set file2Content=

rem Read first file in "file1Content" variable, split lines by slash
for /f %%a in (Document1.csv) do (
    set file1Content=!file1Content!/%%a
)
rem Remove first leading slash
set file1Content=!file1Content:~1!

rem Read second file in "file2Content" variable, split lines by slash
for /f %%a in (Document2.csv) do (
    set file2Content=!file2Content!/%%a
)
rem Remove first leading slash
set file2Content=!file2Content:~1!

set rest1=
set rest2=
for /L %%a in (1,1,999999) do (
    set item1=
    set item2=
    rem Take first line from "!file1Content!"
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=/" %%x in ("!file1Content!") do (
        set item1=%%x
        set rest1=%%y
    )
    rem Removing first line (the one we read) from content1
    set file1Content=!rest1!
    rem Exit if there's no content
    if "!item1!"=="" exit

    rem Take first line from "!file2Content!"
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=/" %%x in ("!file2Content!") do (
        set item2=%%x
        set rest2=%%y
    )
    rem Removing first line (the one we read) from content2
    set file2Content=!rest2!
    rem Exit if there's no content
    if "!item2!"=="" exit
    echo !item1!,!item2!>>joined.csv    
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    Here is the command for doing it the easy way

    cut -c7- y.txt | paste -d',' x.txt - > z.txt

    The 'cut' command cuts off the first 6 characters of file y.txt
    The 'paste' command puts together file x.txt with that modified y.txt
    using comma for a separator and puts the results in file z.txt

    for example:

    file x.txt
    col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6
    col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6
    col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6
    col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6

    file y.txt
    ,,,,,,col7,col8,col9
    ,,,,,,col7,col8,col9
    ,,,,,,col7,col8,col9
    ,,,,,,col7,col8,col9

    cut -c7- y.txt | paste -d',' x.txt - > z.txt

    file z.txt
    col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9
    col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9
    col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9
    col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9
```